# jquery top scrollbar stops working when window resize to less than 90%

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, .net

I am using ASP.NET VB and I have implemented a top scrollbar that imitates the default bottom scrollbar.
for some reason... when I resize the window, if the size goes below 90% the top scrollbar stops functioning.. it continues to function as soon as the size goes back to 90% or above...
I can't find a solution or any help for that matter...

I tried limiting the width to the width that is on 90% (when it still works) but it didn't work... seems like the action of the resize under 90% is doing it alone... not the width itself...
I could be wrong though...

this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        TopScrollBar();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        TopScrollBar();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        TopScrollBar();
    });

    function TopScrollBar() {
        // Set the width of divWidth the same as GridView1
        $('#divWidth').width($('#GridView1').width());

        // Synchronize divScroll's scroll with GridContainer
        $("#divScroll").on('scroll', function () {
            $("#GridContainer").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
        });

        // Synchronize GridContainer's scroll with divScroll
        $("#GridContainer").on('scroll', function () {
            $("#divScroll").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="divScroll" style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; height: 20px;"
    <div id="divWidth"></div>
</div>
<div id="GridContainer" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="gridviewStyle" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>


CSS:
.gridviewStyle {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is you're only problem, but [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) usually needs an [off](https://api.jquery.com/off/) before it.

You're adding new event listeners without removing the old ones.

Try this:

```
    function TopScrollBar() {
        // Set the width of divWidth the same as GridView1
        $('#divWidth').width($('#GridView1').width());

        // Synchronize divScroll's scroll with GridContainer
        $("#divScroll").off('scroll').on('scroll', function () {
            $("#GridContainer").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
        });

        // Synchronize GridContainer's scroll with divScroll
        $("#GridContainer").off('scroll').on('scroll', function () {
            $("#divScroll").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion but this did not help...